# Installing vendored_frameworks from private podspec fails with :git => url in Podfile

Tags: cocoapods

Here is what I am trying to do:

Installing private pod with `vendored_frameworks`.
`MyFramework.podspec` looks like

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "MyFramework"
  spec.summary      = "My summary"
  spec.version      = "1.0.0"
  spec.homepage     = "https://www.google.com"
  spec.authors      = { "Me" => "me@gmail.com" }
  spec.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  spec.source       = { :http => "url to my zip containing the three frameworks" }
  spec.platform     = :ios, "10.0"
  spec.preserve_paths = 'MyFramework1.framework', 'MyFramework2.framework', 'MyFramework3.framework'
  spec.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MyFramework1.framework', 'MyFramework2.framework', 'MyFramework3.framework'
  spec.xcconfig = { 'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => "'${PODS_ROOT}/MyFramework1'"}
  spec.frameworks = 'MyFramework1', 'MyFramework2', 'MyFramework3'
end
```

And my `Podfile` line looks like

```
pod 'MyFramework1', :git => 'myUrl.git'
```

The `pod spec lint .` is working well and also the `pod repo push ...`.
Unfortunately, **the three frameworks are not installed** when I'm doing `pod install`.

However, I discovered that if I change my `Podfile` with

```
pod 'MyFramework1', :podspec => '/path/to/podspec'
```

everything is working fine and I got the three frameworks when I'm doing `pod install`.

Of course, I checked that the `podspec` is exactly the same as the one on my repo git.

What should I do to get it working with `:git => url`?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to do install_framework command